# Java Arrays of Objects with Constructors

Tags: java, arrays

`Player [] array name = new Player[array size];`
My assignment is "What you’ll now need to do is invoke your constructor Player() for each array element. Code a `for-loop` that
loops from 0 to teamsize - 1 and set the `i`th array element to new Player()."

I tried this:

```
Player [] Hits = new Player[20];
for (i = 0; i < teamsize --1; i++)
{
  // this part I have no idea how to do
}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Your first line made the array. Your line where you say you don't know what to do is where you *fill* your array. Can you think of a way to use the index i to put something in each spot in the array? I bet they covered that in class...

Comment: What is teamsize set too? does that even compile?Your for loop condition is wrong it should be teamsize -1 not --1.

Answer (score 1):

in the for :

```
Hits[i] = new Player();
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are fairly straigh-forward:

You have a bug here :

```
for (i = 0; i < teamsize - 1; i++) /*  it is not -- , just - )
{
   Player[i] = /* fill in this part */

}
```